# Find the equation of the curves for which the length of tangent at any point is $1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Find the equation of the curves for which the length of tangent at any point is $1$.

This question seems to be of differential equations.But i am confused while framing the differential equation as the external point from where the tangent is drawn is not in the question.

Am i thinking in the right direction.Please help me in reaching the answer.Its answer given in the book is $\sqrt{1-y^2}+\log\frac{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}{|y|}=\pm x+c$

Comment: @Henry,only this much is given in the question.I feel length of tangent may be length of tangent intercepted between $x$ axis and the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this kinda context, "length of tangent" usually means the distance between the point of contact and the point where the tangent meets the X-axis. So we can set up the differential equation as:
$$y \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{(y')^2}}=\pm 1$$